# Convex Hull In C

Tags: c

I wanted to take points (x,y) as inputs. And I wanted to show the points which makes the convex hull.But it crashed! Can u help me giving advice!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define pi 3.14159
```

//struct point in 2d space

```
typedef struct v1
 {
 int x, y;
}vertex;
vertex p0;
```

//swap two points

```
void swap(vertex *v1, vertex *v2)
{
vertex temp = *v1;
*v1 = *v2;
*v2 = temp;
}
```

//If the points co linear=0, clockwise=1;anticlockwise=2

```
int orientation(vertex p, vertex q, vertex r)
{
int val = ( int)(q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - ( int)(q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);
if (val == 0) return 0;
return (val > 0)? 1: 2;
}
```

//distant between points

```
int distSq(vertex p1, vertex p2)
{
return ( int)(p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) + ( int)(p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y);
}
```

//qsort compare function

```
int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
{
   vertex *p1 = (vertex *)vp1;
   vertex *p2 = (vertex *)vp2;

 int o = orientation(p0, *p1, *p2);
 if (o == 0)
 return (distSq(p0, *p2) >= distSq(p0, *p1))? -1 : 1;

 return (o == 2)? -1: 1;
   }
```

//convex hull function

```
vertex * Convex_Hull(vertex *v)
{
    int n, ymin = v[0].y, min = 0, i,m;
    vertex* stack;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if((v[i].y < ymin) || ((v[i].y == ymin) && (v[i].x < v[min].x)))
        {
        ymin = v[i].y;
        min = i;
        }
}
swap(&v[0], &v[min]);
p0 = v[0];
if(n > 1)
    qsort(&v[1], n - 1, sizeof(vertex), compare);
m = 1;
for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    while((i < n - 1) && orientation(v[0], v[i], v[i + 1]) == 0)
        i++;
    v[m++] = v[i];
}

if(n < 3)
    return v;
stack = (vertex *)malloc(n * sizeof(vertex));
stack[0] = v[0];
stack[1] = v[1];
stack[2] = v[2];
m = 2;
for(i = 3; i < n; i++)
{
    while(orientation(stack[m-1], stack[m], v[i]) != 2)
        m--;
    stack[++m] = v[i];
}

free(v);
return stack;
}
```

//main function where points were taken as inputs

```
int main()
{
int t, n, i, *a, count;
int area;
vertex v[100],*V;
scanf("%d", &t);
while(t--)
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%d %d\n",&v[i].x,&v[i].y);

    V = Convex_Hull(v);
 n=sizeof(V)/sizeof(vertex);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d %d",V[i].x,V[i].y);

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 #define pi 3.14159
 typedef struct v1
{
      int x, y;
}vertex;
vertex p0;
int process_vertices(  int n, vertex *v)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) scanf(" %d %d",&v[i].x,&v[i].y);
  return n;
}
void swap(vertex *v1, vertex *v2)
{
    vertex temp = *v1;
    *v1 = *v2;
    *v2 = temp;
}
int orientation(vertex p, vertex q, vertex r)
{
 int val = (int)(q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - ( int)(q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);
if (val == 0) return 0;
return (val > 0)? 1: 2;
}
 int distSq(vertex p1, vertex p2)
{
    return (int)(p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) + ( int)(p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y     - p2.y);
}
 int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
 {
   vertex *p1 = (vertex *)vp1;
    vertex *p2 = (vertex *)vp2;


    int o = orientation(p0, *p1, *p2);
    if (o == 0)
     return (distSq(p0, *p2) >= distSq(p0, *p1))? -1 : 1;

    return (o == 2)? -1: 1;
 }
vertex * Convex_Hull(vertex *v,  int *count)
{
 int n = *count, ymin = v[0].y, min = 0, i,m;vertex *stack;
for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if((v[i].y < ymin) || ((v[i].y == ymin) && (v[i].x < v[min].x)))
    {
        ymin = v[i].y;
        min = i;
    }
}
swap(&v[0], &v[min]);
p0 = v[0];
if(n > 1)
    qsort(&v[1], n - 1, sizeof(vertex), compare);
     m = 1;
for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    while((i < n - 1) && orientation(v[0], v[i], v[i + 1]) == 0)
        i++;
    v[m++] = v[i];
}
*count = n = m;
if(n < 3)
    return v;
  stack = (vertex *)malloc(n * sizeof(vertex));
stack[0] = v[0];
stack[1] = v[1];
stack[2] = v[2];
m = 2;
for(i = 3; i < n; i++)
{
    while(orientation(stack[m-1], stack[m], v[i]) != 2)
        m--;
    stack[++m] = v[i];
}
*count = n = ++m;
free(v);
return stack;
}

 int main()
{
 int t, n, i,count;

 vertex *v;


    scanf("%d", &n);


    v = (vertex *)malloc( n * sizeof(vertex));
    count = process_vertices(n, v);

    v = Convex_Hull(v, &count);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++) printf("%d %d\n",v[i].x,v[i].y);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: After a stormy night!!!